# Work email field is empty in sharepoint group

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, office-365-groups

When a create a group a put the members of it inside the group. If i look at site permissions (in members group) there will be only one "user" (Ad group) with the same name of the office 365 group that generated the site.

Then, I am using microsoft flow to send a email to the email of the office 365 group created. To do this I make a query to Sharepoint API like this: `_api/web/SiteGroups/GetById(5)/Users`. However, when a get the only one member returned by this request, which is the "user" that has the same name of the office 365 group, the email field is empty.

Someone knows why this is happening? I need the group email to send a message, but the email field return by  `_api/web/SiteGroups/GetById(5)/Users` is empty, when it should be filled.

Answer (score 0):

**Email of the Office 365 group is the same like the Title or URL right? You can create an email from title@domain.com.** Office 365 mailbox is like a Shared Mailbox. This information is not on SharePoint.

You need to work with Office 365 Emails, not with SharePoint groups.